# How do you store unsigned 64-bit integers in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, unsigned

I work with an application which uses rather big numbers and I need to store data as an unsigned 64-bit integer.  I prefer to just store it without worrying about bit manipulation or anything like that so different programs can use the data in different ways.

Answer (score 5):

You can store the value in a `NUMERIC` type with a `scale` of 0, which will retain the `integer` semantics required.  The `NUMERIC` type will allow negative numbers, although you could set up a constraint to require positive integers.

The maximum `precision` for `NUMERIC` is 38 decimal digits. `2**64` is somewhere around 18 or 19 decimal digits, so `NUMERIC(19,0)` would likely work just fine for this data.

Comment: Isn't 2 to the power of 64 '18,446,744,073,709,551,616' - or 20 digits?

If so, would that mean you need a NUMERIC(20,0) to store it?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, You would have to create a custom type. Pointers [here](http://www.julian-kuiters.id.au/article.php/sqlserver2005-unsigned-integer) although that article is more for restricting negative numbers...

Answer (score 0):

Do not switch to the larger datatype just to accomodate the unsigned value. In C# and likewise for other languages cast the ulong (=unsigned 64 bit) value to the long (=signed 64 bit) and store that as a SQL-Server bigint (=signed 64 bit). On the way back read the bigint as a long and C#-cast it to ulong. All values survive, all bits are used, no excess bits are introduced.